# setclip method in iOS image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to know how to clip an image in iOS.  I already have this working in `J2ME` using the canvas set clip method. Now I want to know how I can do this in iOS. Here is an example of what I want.

This is the original image what I'm drawing in storyboard

[image: this this image the original image what i'm drawing in storybord]

[image: this is the image what i want to do. i want to hide the some part of that red image]

This is the image what I want to achieve. I want to hide the some part of that red image.

I tried something like this, but I can't what I want.

```
 UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 ,305, 98, 139)];
    imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"];

    imv.frame = CGRectMake(0 ,305, 98, redImageHeight);
    imv.clipsToBounds = YES;
    imv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;
    [self.view addSubview:imv];
```

Comment: Do you want to resize image fill imageview's bounds?

Comment: @George i did't get you. can you show me some code or explain me more ..

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
imv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

Answer (score 0):

**why don't you use multi-clip of this bar and display one by one I think it will be much easier**